# pivot a table with cell name as column name

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table structure is :

```
year | code | name| value | wef        | 
2014 | a001 | abe | 2000  | 2014-04-01 | 
2014 | a001 | def | 3000  | 2014-05-01 |
2014 | a002 | abe | 2000  | 2014-06-01 |
2014 | a003 | def | 2000  | 2014-04-01 |
2014 | a003 | mno | 5000  | 2014-06-01 |
```

i need result in format as:

```
year | code | abe | abe__wef | def | def__wef  | mno | mno____wef |   
2014 | a001 | 2000|2014-04-01|3000 | 2014-05-01|     |  
2014 | a002 | 2000|2014-06-01|     |           |     | 
2014 | a003 |     |          |2000 | 2014-04-01| 5000| 2014-06-01
```

Comment: IN the name column you have just 3 distinct values or more?Or in other words do you need dynamic sql or not?

Comment: Aaron's article - [Script to create dynamic PIVOT queries in SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/) will help you.

Comment: if the table isn't big, you can use Excel to do this transformation: export the data to excel, and create the "create table" command using the excel itself

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to get the result but since you have multiple values that you want to convert into columns, you will first want to look at unpivoting the `value` and `wef` columns first.

You didn't specify which version of SQL Server you are using but you can use either the [`UNPIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function or you can use [`CROSS APPLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with `VALUES` or `UNION ALL` to convert `value`/`wef` into multiple rows.

The syntax will be similar to:

```
select year, code, col, val
from dbo.yourtable
cross apply
(
  select name, convert(varchar(10), value) union all
  select name+'_wef', convert(varchar(10), wef, 120)
) c (col, val);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b618/3).  This converts your data into the format:

```
| YEAR | CODE |     COL |        VAL |
|------|------|---------|------------|
| 2014 | a001 |     abe |       2000 |
| 2014 | a001 | abe_wef | 2014-04-01 |
| 2014 | a001 |     def |       3000 |
| 2014 | a001 | def_wef | 2014-05-01 |
| 2014 | a002 |     abe |       2000 |
| 2014 | a002 | abe_wef | 2014-06-01 |
```

Now you can apply the `PIVOT` function:

```
select year, code,
  abe, abe_wef, def, def_wef, mno, mno_wef
from
(
  select year, code, col, val
  from dbo.yourtable
  cross apply
  (
    select name, convert(varchar(10), value) union all
    select name+'_wef', convert(varchar(10), wef, 120)
  ) c (col, val)
) d
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for col in (abe, abe_wef, def, def_wef, mno, mno_wef)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b618/4).

The problem that you might run into with the version above is it works great when you have a limited number of values because you can hard-code the query. But if you have an unknown number of values, then the solution won't work. In situations where you have an unknown number of values then you will need to use dynamic sql to get the final result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col) 
                    from dbo.yourtable
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select name, 1 union all
                      select name+'_wef', 2 
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by col, so
                    order by col, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT year, code,' + @cols +N' 
            from 
            (
              select year, code, col, val
              from dbo.yourtable
              cross apply
              (
                select name, convert(varchar(10), value) union all
                select name+''_wef'', convert(varchar(10), wef, 120)
              ) c (col, val)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(val)
                for col in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b618/11). Both versions will give a result of:

```
| YEAR | CODE |    ABE |    ABE_WEF |    DEF |    DEF_WEF |    MNO |    MNO_WEF |
|------|------|--------|------------|--------|------------|--------|------------|
| 2014 | a001 |   2000 | 2014-04-01 |   3000 | 2014-05-01 | (null) |     (null) |
| 2014 | a002 |   2000 | 2014-06-01 | (null) |     (null) | (null) |     (null) |
| 2014 | a003 | (null) |     (null) |   2000 | 2014-04-01 |   5000 | 2014-06-01 |
```